# How to show $\eta\cdot g:X\longrightarrow U$ is continuous?

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X, \mathscr{T})$ be a topological space and $U\in \mathscr{T}$. Suppose $\eta:X\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ is a continuous function such that $\textrm{supp}(\eta)\subset U$ and let $g:U\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ be continuous. Define $\eta\cdot g:X\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ setting $$(\eta\cdot g)(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}\eta(x)g(x)&\textrm{se}& x\in U\\ 0&\textrm{se}&x\not\in U\end{array}\right..$$ How to show this functions is continuous?

I'm trying to do this using open sets: For example, if $V\in \mathscr{T}_{\mathbb R}$ and $0\not\in V$ I think $$(\eta\cdot g)^{-1}(V)=U\cap\eta^{-1}(\mathbb R\setminus\{0\})\cap g^{-1}(\mathbb R\setminus \{0\})\cap ((\eta\cdot g)\circ \imath)^{-1}(V),$$ where $\imath:U\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ is the inclusion. I think $\eta\cdot g|_U$ is continuous so that $(\eta\cdot g)^{-1}(V)$ would be open (if this reasoning is right). I still couldn't figure out the case $0\in V$.

Comment: Isn't it continuous on $U$, as well as on the open $X-supp(\eta)$ ?

Comment: Do you mean for me to use $X=(X\setminus \textrm{supp}(\eta))\cup U$ so that I should only check $\eta(x)\cdot g(x)=0$ for $x\in U\cap \textrm{supp}(\eta)^c$?

Comment: Yes, this is called "gluing lemma" which allows one to check continuity of piece wisely defined functions. See Munkres' book for instance.

Comment: Well, the problem is that I guess I can't assure $\eta(x)\cdot g(x)=0$ for every $x\in U\cap \textrm{supp}(\eta)^c$..

Comment: If $x$ is not in the support, then $\eta(x)=0$.

Comment: Yes that is true.. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The support $\operatorname{supp}(\eta)$ of $\eta$ by definition equals the set $\overline{\{x \in X: \eta(x) \neq 0 \} }$. Denote by $V$ the set $X \setminus \operatorname{supp}(\eta)$, which is open.

For $x \in V$, $\eta(x) = 0$ (as otherwise $x$ would have been in $\operatorname{supp}(\eta)$). As $\operatorname{supp}(\eta) \subset U$, we have that $U \cup V = X$, for as $x \notin V$ then $x \in \operatorname{supp}(\eta) \subset U$.

So in fact, if $g : U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, we can define $(\eta \cdot g)(x)$ as $\eta(x)g(x)$ for $x \in U$ and $0$ for $x \in V$. Both partial functions are clearly continuous on their domains, and on the overlap $U \cap V$ we have that the definitions agree, as $x \in V$ implies $\eta(x) = 0$ so $\eta(x)g(x) = 0$ for such $x$.

So we can then directly apply the [glueing or pasting lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasting_lemma) for open sets (which even applies to arbitrary unions of open sets, or locally finite families of closed sets) to get continuity of the total function.